# Was Australia successful in reducing the Covid-19 cases in the Melbourne towers, following the "hard lockdown"?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, non-pharmaceutical-interventions

The BBC [reported](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-australia-53317324) in July that 3,000 people in low-income public housing were put in "hard lockdown" in Melbourne (10 zip codes and/or [nine tower blocks](https://lens.monash.edu/@politics-society/2020/07/05/1380787/nine-melbourne-tower-blocks-put-into-hard-lockdown-what-does-it-mean-and-will-it-work)), meaning their inhabitants were not allowed to leave their apartments, in a move reminiscent of Chinese measures in Wuhan. (Food was delivered to the apartments.) Was this intervention successful in reducing Covid-19 incidence in the area, and if so to what degree?

(The "hard" lockdown has since been [lifted](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2020/aug/04/we-are-all-breaking-down-in-here-melbourne-towers-residents-too-traumatised-to-go-outside), meaning that the inhabitants were then subject [only](https://www.dhhs.vic.gov.au/information-and-supports-public-housing-restrictions-covid-19) to the broader restrictions that apply elsewhere in the city, but I don't see information in the follow-up article[s] whether the "hard" lockdown has been successful in achieving its medical goals.)